# Android SQLite как проверить существование записи БД с определённым значением определённого столбца?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, recyclerview

Ситуация такая , я беру данные с Firebase и показываю в RecyclerView.

```
private void showData(){
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Ander>().setQuery(mRef,Ander.class).build();


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ander, ViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Ander model) {
            holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getSongName(), model.getSongSinger(), model.getkzSongytblink(), model.getKzSongAuthorName(), model.getkzSongComposerName(), model.getSongText());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false );
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);

            // слушатель при нажатии на кнопку
            viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    String mSongName = getItem(position).getSongName();
                    String mSingerName = getItem(position).getSongSinger();
                    String kzComposer = getItem(position).getkzSongComposerName();
                    String kzAuthor = getItem(position).getKzSongAuthorName();
                    String kzSongText = getItem(position).getSongText();
                    String kzYtbLink = getItem(position).getkzSongytblink();

                    //Pass this data to new Activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PostDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("songname", mSongName);
                    intent.putExtra("singername", mSingerName);
                    intent.putExtra("composername", kzComposer);
                    intent.putExtra("authorname", kzAuthor);
                    intent.putExtra("songtext", kzSongText);
                    intent.putExtra("ytblink", kzYtbLink);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                @Override
                public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            });

            return viewHolder;
        }
    };

    //set layout as LinearLayout
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

    //set adapter to firebase recycler
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

И так я теперь делаю так ,что бы можно было определенный элемент в списке добавлять в список важных.Делаю я это с таким способом.

```
btnFav = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    btnFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String fSongName = getIntent().getStringExtra("songname");
            String fSingerName = getIntent().getStringExtra("singername");
            String fComposerName = getIntent().getStringExtra("composername");
            String fAuthorName = getIntent().getStringExtra("authorname");
            String fSongText = getIntent().getStringExtra("songtext");
            String fSongGenre = getIntent().getStringExtra("songgenre");
            Video_Id = getIntent().getStringExtra("ytblink");


            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put(FavoriteDbHelper.KEY_SONG_NAME, fSongName);
            contentValues.put(FavoriteDbHelper.KEY_SINGER_NAME, fSingerName);
            contentValues.put(FavoriteDbHelper.KEY_SONG_COMPOSER, fComposerName);
            contentValues.put(FavoriteDbHelper.KEY_SONG_AUTHOR, fAuthorName);
            contentValues.put(FavoriteDbHelper.KEY_SONG_TEXT, fSongText);
            contentValues.put(FavoriteDbHelper.KEY_SONG_YTBLINK, Video_Id);
            contentValues.put(FavoriteDbHelper.KEY_SONG_GENRE, fSongGenre);

            database.insert(FavoriteDbHelper.TABLE_FAV, null, contentValues);
            dbHelper.close();

        }
    });
```

Правда  , это кнопочка в DetailActivity.Теперь такой вопрос, если нажимать на эту кнопочку он будет добавлять столько раз сколько вы нажмете. Мне же нужно что бы он проверял наличие в Локальной БД Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать первичные ключи.

Например можно использовать ID во внешней базе.

Добавить в таблицу столбец с **integer primary key _id**.

При записи в локальную БД нужно либо проверять, что такой записи нет в БД, чтобы успешно выполнить insert, либо использовать **insertWithOnConflict**, и каждый раз перезаписывать данные.

Comment: ID , у меня есть в таблице. Вот только не пойму как будет сверять ID. если в  firebase вроде нет ID. там position.

Comment: @ЖанболатМаратов даже там есть ID элемента.

Comment: окей , щас будем разбираться)